# Async post with VueJS and Axios

Tags: javascript, rest, api, vue.js, axios

I have the methods and created properties in VueJS

```
created() {
  axios.get('/wp-json/wp/v2/users/' + portal.user.id + '?context=edit', {headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': portal.nonce}})
  .then(response => {
    this.user = response.data;
  })
  .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e);
  });

  axios.get('/wp-json/wp/v2/categories')
  .then(response => {
    this.terms = response.data;
  })
  .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e);
  });
},

methods: {
  createPost: function() {

    let title = this.new_post_title;
    let content = this.new_post_content;
    let tags = this.new_post_tags;
    let status = this.status;

    let data = {
      'title': title, 
      'content': content, 
      'status': status,
    };

    axios.post("/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/", data, {headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': portal.nonce}})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e);
      console.log(this.errors);
    });

    this.new_post_title = '';
    this.new_post_content = '';
    this.new_post_tags = '';
  }
},
```

Everything is working with the request, the data is being posted to WordPress and when i do a page refresh, I get the new post at the top of the page like it should be.

But how do I go about getting the page to load the new post asynchronously after the request is completed?

Comment: If the post request is successful, then i would just insert the posted data into the page with Vue, inside the `then` callback.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more with a small code snippet? I've only been using Vue for about a month now.

Comment: Yeah. which url gets the posts? `'/wp-json/wp/v2/categories'`?

Comment: /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?context=edit&_embed=true

Comment: So the component where you list the posts, is different than the component where you create posts? Because i don't see that get request in your example.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is in a different component.

Answer (score 0):

If your post gets created successfully, that means if you make a `get` request to the posts endpoint, you would get that newly created post. As you would with a page refresh. So my point is to just directly insert the new post into the page, on the client side, after a successful post request. No get request necessary.

I don't know the structure of your component hierarchy, or whether you're using Vuex. But from the component that created the post, you would `$emit` an event that contains the new post data.

```
createPost: function() {

    let title = this.new_post_title;
    let content = this.new_post_content;
    let tags = this.new_post_tags;
    let status = this.status;

    let data = {
      'title': title, 
      'content': content, 
      'status': status,
    };

    axios.post("/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/", data, {headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': portal.nonce}})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.$emit('new-post',data)
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e);
      console.log(this.errors);
    });

    this.new_post_title = '';
    this.new_post_content = '';
    this.new_post_tags = '';
  }
```

The parent of this component would catch the event, containing the data. Continue emitting events or passing props until you reach the component that displays the list. Once you're in the list component, push the new post into the posts array, and it'll show up on the page.